# Magento 2: Rest api for getting cart items is returns empty array

Tags: magento2, api

I need to get current customer cart items using rest API, so I've created a Cart module and

Here is my interface:

```
<?php

namespace Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart;

interface MyCartInterface{

/**
* @api
* @return array
*/

public function getItems();

}

?>
```

here is my class that implements the interface:
<?php

```
namespace Bit68\Cart\Model\Cart;
use Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart\MyCartInterface;
use \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface;

class MyCart implements MyCartInterface{
/**
* @var Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart\CartInterface
*/
private $cartObj;

public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartObj){
    $this->cartObj = $cartObj;
}

/**
* @api
* @return array
*/

public function getItems(){
    $items = $this->cartObj->getQuote()->getAllItems();
    return $items;
}
}

?>
```

Here is webapi.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">

<route url="/V1/cart/items" method="GET">
    <service class="\Bit68\Cart\Api\Cart\MyCartInterface" method="getItems"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

and that's where I call my api:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 /*
 *  base url of the magento host
 */
 $host = 'http://127.0.0.1/yourParts/';

 //unset($_SESSION['access_token']);
 if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
 echo 'Authenticating...<br>';
 /*
 * authentication details of the customer
 */
 $username = 'mail';
 $password = 'password';
 $postData['username'] = $username;
 $postData['password'] = $password;

 /*
 * init curl
 */
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.'rest/V1/integration/customer/token');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
/*
 * set content type and length
 */
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type: application/json',
       'Content-Length: '.strlen(json_encode($postData)),
   )
);
/*
* set post data
*/
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($postData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($postData));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
/*
* access token in JSON format
*/
echo $output;
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $output;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
   /*
   * create headers for authorization
   */
   $headers = array(
       'Authorization: Bearer '.json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']),
   );
   echo '<pre>';
   echo 'api call... with key: '.$_SESSION['access_token'].'<br><br><br>';
   $ch = curl_init();
   /*
   * set API resource URL
   */
   
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host.'rest/V1/cart/items');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   $output = curl_exec($ch);
   
   curl_close($ch);
   echo '<br>';
   echo gettype($output);
   echo '<br>';
   echo $output;
   echo '<br>';
   echo "Today is " . date("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
   /*
    * json response need to rtrim with [], some times it is appended to the response so the json becomes invalid so need to rtrim the response
   */
   $test = json_decode(rtrim($output, '[]'));
   echo '
   =========================RESPONSE================================<br>
   ';

   print_r($test);
  // echo($test->item_id);
 }
 exit(0);

 ?>
```

and that is my module tree structure

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below code to get cart items of a customer.

```
public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Api\QuoteManagement $quote){
    $this->quoteManagement = $quote;
}

/**
* @api
* @return array
*/

public function getItems(){
    $items = $this->quoteManagement->getCartForCustomer($customerId);
    return $items;
}
```

I am sure it'll work for you so try it.

Comment: Did it work for you ? If yes then please accept. It'll help others.